# Extracting old data from a DOS software

Tags: batch-file, dos, legacy, data-extraction

I have an old software created on DOS. All I have is an executable which shows me the UI. What this software does is it takes details of an order given to a door manufacturing company, stores it somewhere and sends the data to a needle printer. The data stored includes things like the name and address of the customer, door dimensions and so on.

The original creators of the software are no longer reachable and I have no idea what language was used to create it. My company wishes to get rid of this system but right now the only way to access information about old orders is by inserting the order number into the UI.

What I need to do is extract this data and convert it to some readable format, I have read research papers, searched this website and many others but have come up empty. I know that when I enter a new order the files that get modified have the following formats:

^01, WRK, DBK, STA

There are other files in the directory with formats like .ALT, .DBI, .ASC, .BAS, .DDF, .MA3 but those dont seem to have changed in the last 20 years.

Thank you very much in advance guys

Comment: Probably belongs on http://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/, as this is not a question related to any code you *wrote*. But did you check if the '20 years old' files with extension .BAS might actually be the source code in a variant of BASIC?

Comment: In MSDOS days there were keyboard buffer stuffing utilities to 'type' text into a program and TSR programs which can read the screen.

Comment: One of the files has to contain the data. I'd start opening them in a text editor to see if you can ascertain anything about the format. You might get lucky and find a delimited plain text file.

Comment: Thanks for the reply guys, there doesnt seem to be a single file with the data in any readable format, just bits and pieces scattered around and mixed in with a lot of "DEL", "NULL" and so on. I did a little more digging around and did actually find the .BAS file with the code, now trying to understand it and figure out how to get the old data back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The file extensions aren't always the best way of finding out things. File extensions are fluid and there's never been much in the way of standardisation, or at least not back in the DOS days. If you look at [FilExt](http://filext.com/alphalist.php), for example, there's a fair bit of double up.

You'd be better off running the files through a tool like [TrID/32 - File Identifier v2.10 - (C) 2003-11 By M.Pontello](http://mark0.net/soft-trid-e.html) which does a good job of recognising files by their content rather than their file extension. It's not foolproof but can identify a few thousand different file types.

I used to do a lot of development on DOS back in the day. If you want to contact me off list, bruce dot axtens at gmail dot com, I can help identify the files and perhaps cook up a mechanism to extract the data.

Comment: Hi Bruce. Sorry for such a late reply. For some reason I only saw your reply now. I've completed the project a while back but I just wanted to thank you anyway for the offer.

Comment: Hi @O.Fouda could you please give some info about the solution of your problem.

I face a similar one and i would like to learn more details about it!